(NOBRIDGE) ERROR Warning: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component
I’ve ensured that all of my text strings are wrapped in  components, and I’ve also verified that my imports are correct. Is there something I might be missing or another common mistake that could cause this issue? Could this be related to how I’m using third-party libraries or components?
However, the error persists. Here’s the relevant code snippet:
import React from 'react'
import { Text } from "@/components/ui/text"
import { VStack } from "@/components/ui/vstack"
import { Input, InputField, InputSlot, InputIcon, EyeOffIcon } from "@/components/ui/input"
import { Icon, AlertCircleIcon } from "@/components/ui/icon"
import { Heading } from "@/components/ui/heading"

import {
    Button,
    ButtonText,
    ButtonSpinner,
    ButtonIcon,
    ButtonGroup,
  } from "@/components/ui/button"
import { 
    FormControl, 
    FormControlError, 
    FormControlErrorText, 
    FormControlErrorIcon, 
    FormControlLabel, 
    FormControlLabelText, 
    FormControlLabelAstrick, 
    FormControlHelper, 
    FormControlHelperText 
  } from '@/components/ui/form-control'



  function LoginScreen() {
    const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = React.useState(false);
    const handleState = () => {
      setShowPassword((showState) => {
        return !showState;
      });
    };
    return (
      <FormControl
        className='p-4 border rounded-lg border-outline-300'
      >
        <VStack space='xl'>
          <Heading className='text-typography-900 leading-3'>
            <Text>Login</Text>
          </Heading>
          <VStack space='xs'>
            <Text className='text-typography-500 leading-1'>
              Email
            </Text>
            <Input>
              <InputField
                type="text"
              />
            </Input>
          </VStack>
          <VStack space='xs'>
            <Text className='text-typography-500 leading-1'>
              Password
            </Text>
            <Input className='text-center'>
              <InputField
                type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
              />
              <InputSlot className='pr-3' onPress={handleState}>
                <InputIcon as={showPassword ? EyeIcon : EyeOffIcon} className='text-darkBlue-500' />
              </InputSlot>
            </Input>
          </VStack>
          
          <Button
            className='ml-auto'
            onPress={()=>{
              setShowModal(false);
            }}
          >
            <ButtonText className='text-typography-0'>
              <Text>Save</Text>
            </ButtonText>
          </Button>
        </VStack>
      </FormControl>
    )
  }


export default LoginScreen // Export the component
  

